# Is it possible to configure my wireless router such that it does not affect the network topology of my university?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I live in the graduate/Faculty housing at my university. The university supplies an Ethernet drop as well as a in unit wireless router.

When I tried to configure my wireless router for my apartment using the Ethernet drop, I received a message telling me that I must remove the router. The message said that the wireless router would disrupt the network topology.

I was wondering if there would be a way to get around this?

My motivations for this endeavor are the following:

- I would be able to have my own wifi/network with out the limitations put forth by the schools wifi network. (Ie. use chromecast)
- Discontinue my internet service and just use the schools free service.
- Control what information the university tracks about my personal home usage.

The router I have is AsusRT-AC56R DualBand. Any help and advice on such a situation is greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question for many reasons, not knowing your university network topology is one of them. However i would suggest you to stop chasing this one because you could get into trouble for this.

Comment: I totally understand and definitely not trying to cause trouble. My hope is or was that the university didnt want to deal with explaining a complicated method to its users. 

I appreciate the advice, thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though the network administrators have a policy to not to allow student-owned WiFi access-points on their network.  Perhaps they feel that such devices may allow unauthorized hosts to connect, and these hosts may use their network in ways contrary to the school's Acceptable Use Policy, in addition to inherently changing their network's topology.

To use Internet services prohibited by the network administrators of the free campus network, it would seem as having your own personal, paid-for, Internet service independent of the college network, would be an advisable way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)

I would like to clarify that I am not necessarily in pursuit of using prohibited internet services. For instance the school does not block "youtube" or "netflix". Yet the way they have the wifi network set up interferes with the procedure the chromecast uses to setup. This i believe is probably a consequence of prohibiting other sorts of network activity.... 

However I agree that there is chance that they may be specifically blocking chromecast due to their networking nature.

Answer (score 1):

It is, indeed a bad idea to go against your campus network team - and is probably going to land you in more hot water then its worth - particularly if you need to ask SU about how to get arround the restrictions.

**It is not a good idea to follow my thoughts below,** however if you don't care about getting kicked out of college or breaking their user agreements (I assume you are bound by one, I could be wrong) -

You should ascertain how they detected the router on their network.  Most likely it was through its MAC address.  If thats the case, you should be able to reconfigure the router to fake the MAC address of your PC.

If you are using the Uni's WIFI they will be able to track your usage regardless of whether you use a router or not.

You need to ensure that the frequency you are using is at least 3 channels different to the Uni's frequencies in order to prevent interference - and indeed that may not be possible.  (You might have more luck in the 5g band then the 2.4 gig band).

You need to configure the device as a router, rather then a staight access point so you are not bridging your devices straight onto their network.

If they are using any kind of software on your devices to detect the legitimacy of them you may have a problem - you may be able to bypass the problem by forwarding packets to your device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

Now as I have said I definitely do not want to follow a path that has the potential to result in trouble. That being said I will not pursue your thoughts...

However, I am curious as to what one thinks of this general idea. If I have a desktop with to ethernet ports... Can I set it up so that other devices can access the internet through my desktop? Would this make it look as if all the internet activity is coming from the desktop?

Comment: Yes, you can set up your desktop to act as a router using NAT.  (Network Address Translation) - this is pretty standard technology.  If your provider really, really wants to find out if you have stuff going on behind your computer they may be able to analyse ports and browser strings etc, but using NAT on your computer will make it difficult for them to detect stuff automatically - and if your PC is connected to an off-campus VPN and all traffic is routed through it  even more so.

Comment: As I have stated maybe too many times now... I am definitely not trying to stir trouble. So if I proceed with this method would it have any adverse affects on the topology of the network?

Also I do plan  on using a VPN because I find it weird that my girlfriend and  my personal life would be under scrutiny of my school.

Comment: Any use of an unsanctioned WIFI network could have adverse affects on the topology of a network because the amount of frequency is limited and needs to be shared.  By you putting up an AP you could be hurting the layout design the school has put together to make the best use of limited frequency.   Also its probable that bandwidth has been provisioned arround usage assumptions which will no longer hold true if you on-share the connection [ individually this probably has little impact, but it could have a big impact if everyone starts doing it ]